# How to downheap?

Tags: heap

I am currently working on an assignment for a datastructures and algorithms class.
I have to delete the node out of the heap given;

```
         6     after replacing the node ;            20  
       /   \                                        /  \
     11     9                                      11    9
    /  \   / \                                    / \   / \
   17  18 15 10                                  17 18 15 10
  /
 20
```

The question I have is would I downheap to the right, the left or does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a min-heap there, your downheap operation should swap the new parent with the smaller of its children.  Otherwise your swap could result in a violation of the heap condition.

Answer (score 0):

You, need to swap the parent node with that child node which is having the smaller value and this process need to continued untill the base condition for heap is satisfied